# How to load and store a stack of images in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do my first project in MATLAB and so far I try to **load a sequence of images** from a directory and **store them in one object**.

The images are small and they are quite few < 100, so memory is not a problem.

I would optimally store them in a **3 dimensional array**, but I don't know how to do it.

Can you tell me how to load images and store all them in a stack?

So far here is the code I have written:

```
function image = load_image_array(dir, start, finish)
    for i = start:finish

        filename = [ dir '/' sprintf('%08d', i) '.jpg' ];
        image = importdata( filename, 'jpg' );

        figure( i );
        imagesc( image );

    end
end
```

Do you think it is a good idea to preallocate the array in advance? Also, is 3 dimensional array a good idea? I would like to have RGB images, **do I need to have 3 stacks or a 4 dimensional array** for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they're all the same size, storing them in a stack is as simple as:

```
...
imageStack(i,:,:) = image;
...
imagesc( squeeze(imageStack(i,:,:)) );
```

If they're not the same size, just use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html):

```
...
imageStack{i} = image;
...
imagesc( imageStack{i} );
```

My syntax may be off for the cell array, test it out and play with it. I'll try to remember to doublecheck it when I get to work later.

Comment: Thanks. They are the same size.

Comment: @Apoc - Without the squeeze, matlab treats the variable as a 3-D matrix with dimensionality `1xNxM`. With the squeeze, it's a 2-D matrix of size `NxM`. Many matlab functions require a 2-D matrix, and squeeze often comes in handy when pulling slices out of a stack of images.

Comment: You might like to avoid using `image` for a variable name, because it is a built-in MATLAB function.